# Recurrence Relation working

Tags: recurrence

I am doing a data structures and algorithms paper in which recurrence relations are being taught.

The question is as follows:

[image]

From what I understand from this question, n will keep on being halved over and over again. So what you are left with is 1/32n^2 + 1/16n^2 + 1/8n^2 + 1/4n^2 + 1/2n^2 + n^2. All the fractions sum to 1. So you're left with n^2 +n^2 = 2n^2.

However this is not a possible solution.

Can somebody please help me understand how to calculate these recurrence relations correctly, or point me in the right direction because I am having a lot of trouble with this topic and any help with be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think questions like these are much better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com. And your mathematical reasoning was incorrect. If n were 8, you would have 8^2 + 4^2 + 2^2 = 64 + 16 + 4 = 84, which is not equal to 2*(8^2) = 128. And also if you plug 8 into those 5 answer choices, you get A. 14, B. 84, C. 21844, D. 254, E. 4, so B is the only possible answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)

In the wiki, a = 1, b = 2, c = 2, where T(n) = aT(n/b) + n^c

Case 3 applies, since 2 > 0 = log_2(1)

Thus, by the master theorem, T = Big-Theta(n^c) = Big_Theta(n^2).

Choice B has a n^2 term, so that should be your answer.

Comment: This looks like it will be of great use, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Is what I did correct? In terms of my calculation of 2n^2?

Comment: Almost, I think.  Note that T(n/2) = T(n/4) + n^2/4.  And T(n/4) = T(n/8) + n^2/16.  So you get n^2 + n^2/4 + n^2/16 + ...